# Android, using Google Play Services Api connection requires to pay a fee?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, developer-console

I am developing an app which requires to use the Google Play Services API because it is an online multiplayer game and Google Play Services suits me good in about I want to do.

As I read here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart 
it requires me to generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID for my app in order to connect to the API properly and employ its services and in order to get the OAuth 2.0 client ID I need to create an account in Google Play Developer Console which requires me to pay a fee of 25$.

Since I am not completely sure about and costs me money to test it I ask if I am sure and I need to pay the fee or I am wrong about.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Developer Console account to publish your app. The $25 fee is a one-time fee. You shouldn't have to pay any additional fees to use the Google Play Services.

Comment: So if I understand properly do I need to pay that fee to use those services contained in Google Play Services? Thanks you for the help.

Comment: The fee is for access to the Developer Console which allows you to publish your app as well as make use of the other services like viewing the statistics. Use of Google Play Services is included and has no extra charge.